# Computer is unable to boot after installing Kali

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, grub

Previous situation was a working dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 10.

I decided to install Kali Linux instead of Ubuntu, so during the installation process, I removed and overwrote both ext4 partitions that contained Ubuntu.

During the installation, Kali told me it was unable to install grub.

Rebooting results in a grub prompt. I am only able to get into Windows by pressing F12 when the Dell logo is visible on screen.

I've tried to fix it by running the boot-repair-disk from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/). This doesn't work, but provides a boot info summary, which [can be found here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25339635/).

Does anyone know how to fix grubso that I can boot into Windows and Kali?

---

Update
I'm currently booted into Kali by using SuperGRUB2 Disk.
When I tried to run `grub-install`, I got `bash: grub-install: command not found`.

I fixed that by removing and reinstalling grub. After that:

```
#sudo fdisk -lu
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0F7188DF-BE33-491B-AE57-6E2E6841C9F0

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1026048    1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1288192  488976383 487688192 232.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 488976384  968964095 479987712 228.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5 968964096 1000214527  31250432  14.9G Linux swap

#grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
grub-install: error: /usr/local/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

Comment: Please be aware that Kali isn't really intended for daily use (it simply isn't. It's possible to make it work by creating a non-root user and stuff, but again, the OS isn't intended for this). I'd advise installing it to a flash drive and booting as necessary, and using a proper OS meanwhile (Ubuntu, Arch, Windows etc). If you really want to use pentesting tools in your daily OS, I'd look at something like ArchStrike.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I use Windows as my daily OS, and found that installing Kali makes it work faster than from my USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had not installed Kali as EFI. After I recreated the USB drive (using Rufus), the reinstall went smoothly.

Comment: Okay, so everything now works fine right?

Answer (score 1):

From your terminal, run the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install boot-repair

$ boot-repair
```

I hope this help fix your GRUB issue